# Why do I sometimes get numbers back from the FileSystemRights access field when checking the ACL Access?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, ntfs, binary

Sometimes I'll run a command like this, and I'll get back some easy to read, easy to interpret text:

```
    PS D:\test> (get-acl test.txt).Access | Select FileSystemRights

   FileSystemRights
   ----------------
   Modify, Synchronize
```

---

...and other times I'll get back a number:

```
    PS D:\test> (get-acl test2.txt).Access | Select FileSystemRights

   FileSystemRights
   ----------------
          268435456
```

What is the number, and what does it mean
?

Comment: What is the system you are running this command on, and is it the same system you created the filesystem in?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I'm running Windows 7 Pro, Powershell 3, on a mapped drive to a `Windows Server 2012 R2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [FileSystemRights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute is an enumeration. However the generic rights will not be enumerated. See output of:

```
[System.Enum]::GetValues([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights])
```

The [Access Mask Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374896(v=vs.85).aspx) defines the upper four bits for [generic access rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446632(v=vs.85).aspx).  These rights are GENERIC_ALL (268435456) -- what you've seen, GENERIC_EXECUTE (536870912), GENERIC_WRITE (1073741824) and GENERIC_READ(2147483648)

Comment: So there are no "new" permissions? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is only an educated guess.

It is a mapped drive on a newer and separate branch of Windows. The Server version most likely has additional ACL rights available, and Windows 7 Pro does not have text descriptions of those ACL rights. Therefore it only shows the numerical value of the ACL.

Comment: Have you a link to a list of these "additional ACL rights"?

Comment: No. As I stated above, this was an educated guess based on my experience with similar systems, and I don't have exact facts on it. I did a short Google search on the subject, but didn't find them. A more thorough search should give you the answer.